# Your Podfile requires that the plugin `cocoapods-patch` be installed

Tags: cocoapods, xcode13

Run pod install and hitting this error. Just upgraded to Xcode 13 beta.

> [!] Your Podfile requires that the plugin `cocoapods-patch` be
> installed. Please install it and try installation again.

How to resolve this?

Comment: Downgraded to Xcode 12.5 and ran $ gem install cocoapods-patch and it works... Not sure why Xcode 13 beta is giving errors to download cocoapods-patch

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is "sudo pod install cocoapods-patch", but this fails because of conflicts of binaries, and if you do not overwrite them, it aborts instead of continuing on with installing other files. Back these files up, overwrite them, and then restore them, and then it will actually be installed.

Comment: do you really meant `sudo pod install` or `sudo gem install` ?

Comment: I've added this package and didn't get that error, which version cocoapods-patch did you install using `gem install cocoapods-patch`?

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo gem install cocoapods-patch
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Exact same issue after doing it.